# Azure Notification Hub "no matchin targets" message after sending message

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, android-notifications

It seems that we programmed everything correctly because when we use a test app that we made everything works fine. But now that were trying to create the real app it doesn't work. When we try to send a push message from Notification Hubs we get the message "message was successfully sent but there were no matching targets". We tripple checked all the necessary fields and everything is the same. Somehow the message is not being delivered and we can't find the reason why.